# removing number keys from php array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, key-value

I want to handle JSON data structures that could look like this:

```
$json = {"1":"some content here","hello":"world"};
```

I use the json_decode method from PHP to transform this into an array:

```
$myArray = (array)json_decode($json);
```

My problem now is that

```
unset($myArray["1"]);
```

Doesn't do anything.

Can you give me any advice? 
I also tried:

```
unset($myArray[(String)"1"]);
```

Thank you!

EDIT: There was an error in my question, thanks for the correction in the comments!

Comment: What about `unset($myArray["1"]);`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply accessed the wrong array

```
unset($myArray["1"]);
unset($myArray[1]); // works also
```